# My button is only clickable once. I'd like to be able to repeat many searches

Tags: javascript, html, flask

My problem is opposite to most people. I want to be able to search for a user multiple times. For example, if I look up Ray, I retrieve ray's data. Then if I look up bob, I want to retrieve bob's data.

However, my code works to retrieve the data from the first search. It then appears your clicking the button, but nothing is happening.

I have not tried much, because I don't know where to start.

```
<div align="center">

</div>
    <!--
    <div class = "box" style = "width:100%; text-align:center;">

        <form method = "POST">
            <input style = "float:left;"type="search" class="form-control" type="text" name = "search" placeholder="Enter First and Last name to begin" aria-label="Search" > </input>
            <button style = "float:right;"type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id ="search" onclick="fetchlist();return false;">Search</button>
        </form>
    --> 

        <div style="text-align: center;">
            {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form method="POST"  action="/">
            <dl style="display: inline-block; text:white;" >{{render_field(form.search)}}           </dl>
            <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;"  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="fetchlist(); return false;">Search</button>   
            <br>
            {% if error %}
            <p class = "error"><strong>Error:</strong>{{error}}</p>
        {% endif %}
        </form>


    </div>

{% if data %}
    <div  style="text-align:center;">   
        <table id="list" style="display:none;" class = "table table-hover" >
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Rating</th>
                <th scope="col">Review</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                {% for row in data %}
                    <tr>
                        {% for d in row %}
                            <td>{{ d }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endif %}
</body>

<script>
function fetchlist() {
    if (document.getElementById('searchbutton').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';
    }
    else document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';

}   
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    try:
        form=SearchForm(request.form)
        global d1
        d1 =""
        if request.method == "POST":
            s1 = form.search.data
            a = s1.split(" ",1)
            firstname, lastname = (a[0], a[1])
            c,conn = connection()
            qry = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM posts WHERE FirstName LIKE (%s) AND LastName like (%s)"
            c.execute(qry, ((thwart(firstname)), (thwart(lastname))))
            d1 = c.fetchall() 
            c.close()
            conn.close()
            print(d1)
        else: print('error')
        return render_template("index.html", data=d1, form = form)
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

No error messages. I expect to perform multiple searches.

Comment: hi if you can provide the HTML output of your flask code then we can help you out with JS

Comment: @Rishab don't know what you mean as the HTML output, but I've added the flask code as well

Comment: `document.getElementById('searchbutton').onclick` returns a 'Function'. I think is not correct what you want. And try the `onclick="fetchlist()"`

Comment: @Marian the function fetchlist makes the table visible. If i remove return false, the page will reload.